# Modification to improve antibacterial activity

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology, drugs

> [image]

I have difficulties with part b).

For **C**, it's clear to make a bulky dimethoxybenzene group in order to block the C=O group from reacting with b-lactamase.

- However, in **A**, how does the structure of sulfonamide affect the bacterial activity in general?
- Is there an alternative for **C** as well?

Comment: I suspect you are reffereing to B on your second paragraph. Also I think 2 structures  being refered here are A and B, they can be directly modified. C on its own has very weak antibacterial activity but serves a useful purpose when used in synergy with potent antibiotics e.g amoxicillin

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the basis of antibacterical activity of sulfonamides is the **inhibition of  the enzyme dihydropteroate synthase**, an
important enzyme needed for the biosynthesis of folic
acid derivatives and, ultimately, the thymidine required
for DNA.

Now they do this by competing at the active
site with **p -aminobenzoic acid (PABA)**, a normal structural
component of folic acid derivatives.

[image]

*PABA*

> So how does the structure of sulfonamide affect the bacterial
> activity in general?

The basis of the structural resemblance of sulfonamides to PABA is clear. The
functional group that differs in the two molecules is the
**carboxyl of PABA** and the **sulfonamide moiety** of sulfanilamide.

Now there are requirements that are vital for activity:

[image]

***Para-amino group:***

- unsubstituted (i.e $\ce{NH2}$).
- very important for activity because any modification of it **other than to
  make prodrugs** results in a loss of activity. *For example, all
  of the N4-acetylated metabolites of sulfonamide are inactive.*

***Sulfonamide:***

- $\ce{N}$ must be primary or secondary
- $\ce{R2}$ can be substituted

***Aromatic ring:***

- Para substituted

**Modifications**

The pKa of the carboxyl group of PABA is
approximately 4.9 thus an optimised sulfonamide has a pKa somewhere close to this value.

> It was observed that replacement of one of the $\ce{NH2}$ hydrogens by
> an electron-withdrawing heteroaromatic ring enhanced the acidity of
> the remaining hydrogen and dramatically enhanced potency.
>
> With suitable groups in place, the pKa is reduced to the same range as
> that of PABA itself. Not only did this markedly increase the
> antibacterial potency of the product, but it also dramatically
> increased the water solubility under physiologic conditions.

Structural variation among the clinically useful sulfonamides
is restricted primarily to installation of ***various
heterocyclic aromatic substituents on the sulfonamide
nitrogen.***

An example  is Sulfisoxazole (pKa 5.0) which can also be formulated as a prodrug, by inclusion of N-acetyl groups. Another advantage is the acetyl derivative
is tasteless and, therefore, suitable for oral administration, especially
in liquid preparations.

---

> Is there an alternative for C as well?

Clavulanic acid is a naturally occurring, mechanism based
inhibitor , which causes potent and
progressive inactivation of β-lactamases.

There  are alternatives e.g sulbactam (A synthetic derivative of penicillins undergone the oxidation of the sulfur atom to a sulfone which greatly
enhances the potency) or tazobactam.

**References**

1. The 12th Edition of Wilson and Gisvold’s Textbook of Organic Medicinal and Pharmaceutical Chemistry
2. Foye’s Principles of Medicinal Chemistry 7th ed.